# Node.js, mongoose and MongoDb - Replace character in certain string in multiple documents

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

So I'm playing with MongoDb database, I've used so far with Python but now I'm trying to conquer Node.js. I've connected to mongo database with mongoose. Configured following schema:

```
var recipeSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    img: String,
    category: String,
    cook_time: String,
    method: String,
    person_count: String,
    short_desc:String,
    ingredients: [
        {
            amount: String,
            ingredient: String
        }
    ],
    recipe: String,
    advice: String

});
var Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);
```

I have filled database with some autamation procedure in python, and the problem I have is that somehow I got the two unwanted charaters `\n` on beginning of my `title` string. I managed to find documents with Mongoose in Node, that has title item which are starting with `\n` with:

```
Recipe.find({ title: /\n/ }, 'title', function (err, document) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log(document)
})
```

I'm little bit newbie in javascript so I'm gonna ask a question which is the best way to replace the `\n` with nothing (I suppose something like `string.replace("\n","")`) and update it back to my mongo database?

Comment: `string.replace("\n", "")` is exactly what you'd do. Did you try that?

Comment: I don't think `.find({ title: /\n/ }, 'title',...` is valid syntax. Also, I don't think Mongo has a find and replace strategy. I would use a cursor and use `string.replace()` as you have it.

Comment: it is valid, I'm getting back wanted docs in console.log. The problem is that I do not know procedure of replacing it and updating it back because im javascript newbie...

Comment: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update

Comment: can I update multiple documents at once with this one?

Answer (score 2):

Suprisingly I think that I succeded with modification of my own code:

```
Recipe.find({ title: /\n/ }, 'title', function (err, document) {

    for (i = 0, max = document.length; i < max; i++) {
        console.log(document[i]);
        var newTitle = document[i].title.replace(/\n/,"");
        document[i].title = newTitle;
        document[i].save(function (err) {
            if(err) {
                console.error('ERROR!');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

I have looped through the found documents and then saved new stuff

Comment: You might find that your documents are not updated here, because Mongoose.js restricts locks the documents that it returns. If that's happening on your end, you'll need to call each document's toJSON() method, make any modifications, and then save the JSON-ified document.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but that code worked for me as it was, documets are updated with new titles... the collection is not something complicated so far so I assume that because of it, this simple code worked for me